# How did you get 75% and 97% with which formula?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you have a slightly biased coin that has a 51% chance of coming up heads and a 49% chance of coming up tails. If you toss it 1,000 times, you will generally get more or less 510 heads and 490 tails, and hence a majority of heads. If you do the math, you will find that the probability of obtaining a majority of heads after 1,000 tosses is close to 75%. The more you toss the coin, the higher the probability (e.g., with 10,000 tosses, the probability climbs over 97%).

My question is how did they calculate the probability of 75 % and 97%

Book: Hands-on Machine learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $N$ independent coin flips of a coin that has probability $p$ of coming up heads, the number of heads $X$ is [binomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). The other answer discussed the precise computation. However, for $N$ large, we can also use an approximation by the central limit theorem, which tells us $X$ will be approximately normal with mean $Np$ and variance $Np(1-p)$, or equivalently, $\frac{X-Np}{\sqrt{Np(1-p)}}$ is approximately standard normal.

Thus, the probability you obtain a majority of heads in $N$ flips, given by

$$P\left(X\geq N/2\right)=P\left(\frac{X-Np}{\sqrt{Np(1-p)}}\geq \frac{\sqrt N(1/2-p)}{{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}}\right),$$

is approximately $$1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt N(1/2-p)}{{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}} \right),$$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal. Yours setup has $p=0.51$.

This approximation gives about 0.74 for [1,000 tosses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard%20normal%20cdf%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22NormalProbabilities%22%2C%20%22z%22%7D%20-%3E%22sqrt%281000%29*%28.5-.51%29%2F%28sqrt%28.51*.49%29%29%22) and about 0.98 for [10,000 tosses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard%20normal%20cdf%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22NormalProbabilities%22%2C%20%22z%22%7D%20-%3E%22sqrt%2810000%29*%28.5-.51%29%2F%28sqrt%28.51*.49%29%29%22).

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of tosses. You are repeating a Bernoulli process (two issues head/tail with $51\%/49\%$). Let $X$ be the number of heads in those $n$ tosses and $p = 0,51$. Then
$$
P\left(X=k\right) = \binom{n}{k}p^k\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}
$$

For example, "obtaining a majority of heads" if $n$ is even is
$$
P\left(X\geq \frac{n}{2}\right) = \sum_{k=n/2}^{n}P\left(X=k\right)
$$
Let $n = 1000$, you obtain
$$
P\left(X\geq \frac{n}{2}\right) = 0,745 \approx 75 \%$$
and with $n = 10 000$ my calculator won't do it but I presume that'll be what you mentioned